# Guidelines for reviewing journal manuscripts

Tags: academic-writing, resources, publisher

Are there good books that give guides to reviewing manuscripts for inclusion in scholarly journals? I'm working in the areas of computers, education, training, and psychology. There are some scattered resources out there, such as [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nits62oGDHU), or [this one](http://advan.physiology.org/content/27/2/47.full), but I'd rather have a more unified resource (or resources).

Comment: By "reviewing", do you mean evaluating them for purchase, reviewing articles for inclusion in the journal, or reviewing in the sense of peer review?

Comment: @NeilFein Ah, I'm sorry for not clarifying it earlier, I am reviewing for inclusion in the journal.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Have included this info in your answer. Please make additional edits if there is information you feel is required - or if you have to to fix anything I may have gotten wrong.

Comment: Maybe you could write one after you have finished your study...

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks for your comment. I completed my study, and I got [P]ermanent [h]ead [D]amage. I am still learning to review manuscript for inclusion in scholarly journals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may not be a direct text that would give you all the necessary information but you could consider looking at the following:

1) Reviewing scientific works in Psychology, Sternberg Robert J. (ed), American Psychological Association (2006)

2) Peer Review and Manuscript Management in Scientific Journals, Hames, Irene, Blackwell Publishing (2007).

The contents of the second book do not talk in depth about the reviewing process but there is a section that covers that. It has got more relevance to the person who is being reviewed. The first book is all about doing the process of review.

Hope these help!